# Reorder the objects in an array by object property numeric values

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, javascript-objects

I have an ionic cordova app I'm working in that runs on typescript. I have an array of objects. Each object contains information for a location. One of the fields in each location is the distance in miles from the user. When printing these locations to the template, I need to print them in order from smallest distance to largest. I'm new to typescript.

Here is an example of my array of objects:

```
    (7) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
    0:Object
        distance:17.24
        emails:"someemail@email.com, anotheremail@email.com"
        location_adress:"555 Address Road, San Antonio, TX, United States"
        location_city:"San Antonio"
        location_fax:"555-555-5551"
        location_id:"1"
        location_image:"http://CDN/path/to/image1.jpg"
        location_latitude:"29.3778525"
        location_longitude:"-98.50377409999999"
        location_name:"Some Name1"
        location_phone:"555-555-5551"
        location_state:"Texas"
        location_status:"1"
        location_street:"555 Address Road"
        location_zip_code:"78214"
        __proto__:Object
    1:Object
        distance:19.994
        emails:"someemail@email.com, anotheremail@email.com"
        location_adress:"556 Address Road, San Antonio, TX, United States"
        location_city:"San Antonio"
        location_fax:""
        location_id:"3"
        location_image:"http://CDN/path/to/image2.jpg"
        location_latitude:"29.4592474"
        location_longitude:"-98.64008209999997"
        location_name:"Some Name2"
        location_phone:"555-555-5552"
        location_state:"Texas"
        location_status:"1"
        location_street:"556 Address Road"
        location_zip_code:"78251"
        __proto__:Object
    2:Object
        distance:14.19
        emails:"someemail@email.com, anotheremail@email.com"
        location_adress:"557 Address Road, San Antonio, TX, United States"
        location_city:"San Antonio"
        location_fax:""
        location_id:"4"
        location_image:"http://CDN/path/to/image3.jpg"
        location_latitude:"29.45775019999999"
        location_longitude:"-98.5540115"
        location_name:"Some Name3"
        location_phone:"555-555-5553"
        location_state:"Texas"
        location_status:"1"
        location_street:"557 Address Street"
        location_zip_code:"78228"
        __proto__:Object
    ...... ect...
```

How can I sort these objects by smallest distance number to largest in my component file? I'll then print the correct order to my template.

Here is the block in my template as-is that prints the objects:

```
  <ion-col col-12 col-sm-6>

    <div class="list-results">

      <div class="zip-result" *ngFor="let item of dataSet" (click)="push(item.location_id)">
        <p class="location-name">{{item.location_name}}</p>
        <p class="address"><ion-icon name="navigate-outline"></ion-icon> {{item.location_adress}}</p>
        <p class="go-to-location">
            <ion-icon name="arrow-forward" ></ion-icon>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-col>
```

This seems so simple yet I can't find anything on this other than "angular2+ does not allow orderBy", no big deal if I can reorder them in the component file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the magic:

```
    this.dataSet = newArr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return parseFloat(a.distance) - parseFloat(b.distance);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For arrays you can just use `sort`, though this will not update automatically if new items are added as a view binding with sort order would:

```
list.sort((a, b) => a.distance - b.distance);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton man, this got me going:

        this.dataSet = newArr.sort(function(a, b) {
            return parseFloat(a.distance) - parseFloat(b.distance);
        });

Comment: Glad to help :)